# How to navigate the drop-down list in Chrome using keyboard?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

In Firefox, while focused on a drop-down box, use ALT-DOWN would display the list so that user can navigate.

But in Chrome, ALT-DOWN does not work, I can only use UP/DOWN to navigate per entry.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there's a shortcut to do that.  It's not listed in the [Chrome Keyboard Shortcuts list](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25799&topic=28650) and I tried every shortcut I could think of in the latest dev Chrome with no success.  I didn't see any issues addressing it in the [Chrome issues database](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) so I created one - [issue 73349](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73349).

Comment: Argh! Deal breaker...

Comment: Alt+Down is not a hotkey in FireFox, it is a Windows keyboard combination (try it in the Run dialog or in Explorer’s address-bar). The problem is that Chrome uses a custom drop-list control from Webkit (for cross-platform compatibility) as opposed to the common-control from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Down works on combo boxes. Chrome address bar does not have combo box in address bar. This is why I prefer other browsers (and don't use Chrome very often).

Answer (score 0):

`Spacebar` works in Chrome v107, just tested